# Evaluate the limit as $r$ tends to $0$ of the intersection of a line with $x$ axis

Tags: limits

A fixed circle $C_1$ with equation $(x-1)^2+y^2=1$ and a shrinking circle $C_2$ with radius $r$ and centre at the origin is given. P is the point $(0,r)$  and $Q$ is the upper  point of intersection of the two circles. $R$ is the point of intersection of the line $PQ$ and the $x$ axis. What are the coordinates of the point $R$ as $C_2$ shrinks i.e. as $r$ tends to $0$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Every time we post a question here we show our advances in the answer or, at least, we point out the particular detail(s) about the question that make it troublesome to us. The community will appreciate if you do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution of the equations $(x-1)^2 + y^2 = 1$ and $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$ are $(r^2/2, r\sqrt{1-r^2/4})$ and $(r^2/2, -r\sqrt{1-r^2/4}))$.

Now, the line passing through $P \equiv (0,r)$ and $Q \equiv (r^2/2, r\sqrt{1-r^2/4})$ has the equation,

$$y = -\frac{1-\sqrt{1-r^2/4}}{r/2}x + r$$

which intersects at $x$ axis at,

$$\left(\frac{r^2}{2-\sqrt{4-r^2}},0\right) \equiv \left(\frac{r^2(2+\sqrt{4-r^2})}{r^2},0\right) \rightarrow (4,0) \text{ as } r \rightarrow 0$$

Comment: -1 almost when I saw your first attempt! +1 now.

Comment: Yes. I made a mistake in the first attempt.

Comment: I had a misleading idea too when I first saw this problem.

Comment: Answer is right

Comment: Please can you solve this i dont know why my profile is banned...

Comment: For a certain value of c lim x tends to-infinity ((x^5+7x^4+2)^c-x) is finite and non zero and has value equal to l .Find the value of (l-2c)